How do I reduce amount of memory used here?
So, I wrote a code, for this problem.
Code :
import copy

class SnapshotArray:

    def __init__(self, length: int):
        self.lst = [0] * length
        self.snap_id = -1
        self.hash = []
        self.by_snap_id = 0
        return None

    def set(self, index: int, val: int) -> None:
        self.lst[index] = val
        return None

    def snap(self) -> int:
        self.snap_id += 1
        self.copy = copy.copy(self.lst)
        self.hash.append(self.copy)
        del self.lst
        self.lst = self.hash[self.snap_id]
        return self.snap_id

    def get(self, index: int, snap_id: int) -> int:
        return self.hash[snap_id][index]

In 69 / 75 testcase it says MLE
So I tried to make just one list from which I'll be taking value for current list too, but it didn't work. So, how do I reduce amount of memory used?

The idea is presumably not to copy the whole array, but just store changes to it...

Probably the issue is you storing multiple copies of the entire list. To optimize memory usage, store only the changes made between snapshots:
class SnapshotArray:
    def __init__(self, length: int):
        self.snapshots = [{}] 
        self.current = {}
        self.snap_id = 0
    def set(self, index: int, val: int) -> None:
        self.current[index] = val
    def snap(self) -> int:
        self.snapshots.append(self.current.copy())
        self.current = {}
        self.snap_id += 1
        return self.snap_id - 1
    def get(self, index: int, snap_id: int) -> int:
        for i in range(snap_id, -1, -1):
            if index in self.snapshots[i]:
                return self.snapshots[i][index]
        return 0


How is this not storing multiple copies of the list (well, dict in this implementation)?

@AKX He created empty dict named current, and then started giving value to each of the indecies that he changed there, basically hashed all the changes. Code is not changing the list as I did, code is storing the changes of indicies.

@AKX each snapshot is stored separately in memory, and changes to one snapshot do not affect the others. It does not store multiple copies of the entire array. Instead, it only stores the changes made to the array at each snapshot. This is more space-efficient than storing a full copy of the array for each snapshot, especially if the array is large and only a few elements change between snapshots.

Right, I somehow missed that current is cleared (or reassigned – in fact, since current is copied into snapshots, this could be made slightly more efficient by self.current.clear() instead of assigning a new empty dict, or the other way around, not copying self.current since it will be reassigned next anyway).

A more efficient approach both time and space-wise would be to use a list for each index to keep track of the snap_ids at which set is called for the index, so that you can use bisect.bisect to find the snap_id closest to the given snap_id in a get call, reducing the time complexity of get to O(log n) while maintaining a space complexity of O(n):
from bisect import bisect

class SnapshotArray:
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.snap_id = 0
        self.snaps = {}
        self.values = {}

    def set(self, index, value):
        if not (snaps := self.snaps.setdefault(index, [])) or snaps[-1] != self.snap_id:
            snaps.append(self.snap_id)
        self.values.setdefault(index, {})[self.snap_id] = value

    def snap(self):
        self.snap_id += 1
        return self.snap_id - 1

    def get(self, index, snap_id):
        if snaps := self.snaps.get(index):
            return self.values[index][bisect(snaps, snap_id) - 1]
        return 0

Demo: https://ideone.com/hgsoes
